# Conditional indexing in metricbeat using Ingest node pipeline creates a datastream

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to achieve conditional indexing for namespaces in elastic using ingest node pipelines. I used the below pipeline but the index getting created when I add the pipeline in metricbeat.yml is in form of datastreams.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/sample-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_index",
        "copy_from": "metricbeat-dev",
        "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace==\"dev\"",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected index name is metricbeat-dev but i am getting the value in _index as .ds-metricbeat-dev.
This works fine when I test with one document but when I implement it in yml file I get the index name starting with .ds- why is this happening?

update for the template :

```
{
   "metricbeat" : {
     "order" : 1,
     "index_patterns" : [
       "metricbeat-*"
     ],
     "settings" : {
       "index" : {
         "lifecycle" : {
           "name" : "metricbeat",
           "rollover_alias" : "metricbeat-metrics"
         },
```

Comment: This is probably because there's an index template for `metricbeat-*` that enables data stream. Can you check what you get when running `GET _template/metricbeat*` ?

Comment: I can find a template that is pointing to my index pattern metricbeat-* could this be the problem?

Comment: Can you update your question with that template definition (no need for mappings and settings section, just the top-level sections)

Comment: updated the question

Comment: The template is not complete, please add the whole template, without the content of `mappings` and `settings`. Also please check the following endpoint `GET _index_template/metricbeat*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data streams enabled in the index templates it has potential to create a datastream. This would depend upon how you configure the priority. If priority is not mentioned then it would create legacy index but if priority higher than 100 is mentioned in the index templates. Then this creates a data stream(legacy index has priority 100 so use priority value more than 100 if you want index in form of data stream).

If its create a data stream and its not expected please check if there is a template pointing to index you are writing where data stream is enabled! This was the reason in my case.

Have been working with this for few months and this is what I have observed!